# Fiji compilation weirdness

Tags: java, windows, imagej

I'm compiling my homemade plugin using Fiji and I'm getting strange results.

For example, if I compile a program `x = 10;` it will run fine.

Say I change `x=10;` to `x=3;` (after i've compiled), every time I compile and run it alternates from `x=10` to `x=3` (back and forth each time).  Does anyone know what could cause this?

I'm on windows, using fiji-win64 latest version.

Comment: In case it wasn't clear I'm using the built-in script editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug: [scijava/scripting-java#5](https://github.com/scijava/scripting-java/issues/5).

When developing Java code for ImageJ, I would suggest using a [full-featured IDE](http://imagej.net/IDEs) such as [Eclipse](http://imagej.net/Eclipse). They are worth the effort to learn.

Comment: Isn't that so strange? I think you're correct about using eclipse, I've been avoiding it but I think it may be the right choice